# Scala inference : fail on 1 evaluation, success with intermediate val

Tags: scala, type-inference

I'm beginner in scala and don't understand what happend here :

Given :

```
val reverse:Option[MyObject] = ...
```

And `myObject.isNaire` return Boolean.

If I do :

```
val v:Option[Boolean] =  reverse.map(_.isNaire)
val b:Boolean = v.getOrElse(false)
```

It work.

Now, If I do :

```
val b:Boolean = reverse.map(_.isNaire).getOrElse(false)
```

It fail to compile with a `type mismatch: found Any, required Boolean`

---

Edit : Thanks Beryllium, by making SSCCE, I found a beginning of explication. In the first example, myObject is a java class, so isNaire is a java.lang.Boolean. I thought implicit conversion should make this transparent so the explanation is still welcome.

```
class Test(val naire:java.lang.Boolean)

class Other {
  val testValue = Some(new Test(true))
  def mysteriousCompilationError:Boolean = testValue.map(_.naire).getOrElse(false)
}
```

Note: ScalaCompiler is 2.10.2

Comment: I could compile a modified version, so please provide a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You would be better off converting the java.lang.Boolean to a scala.Boolean inside the map() function literal, since `false` isn't a value of `java.lang.Boolean`. For example, `def mysteriousCompilationError:Boolean = testValue.map(_.naire == true).getOrElse(false)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `scala.Predef` there's an implicit conversion from `java.lang.Boolean` to `scala.Boolean`:

```
  implicit def Boolean2boolean(x: java.lang.Boolean): Boolean = x.booleanValue
```

So in your first case `val v:Option[Boolean] =  reverse.map(_.isNaire)` the compiler see's a `java.lang.Boolean` and looks for an implicit method in scope to convert it to a `scala.Boolean`, which it conveniently finds in `scala.Predef`.

In you're second case, `testValue.map(_.naire).getOrElse(false)`, the compiler is doing things in this order:

1. `Option[Test] => Option[java.lang.Boolean]`
2. `getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B` where `A` is `java.lang.Boolean` and `B` is `Any` since `scala.Boolean` is not `>:` `java.lang.Boolean`
3. `val b:Boolean`, compiler can't find an implicit conversion from `Any` to `scala.Boolean`

The only way to get around this, is to tell the compiler during the map operation to use the implicit conversion from `scala.Predef` to go from `java.lang.Boolean` to `scala.Boolean`:

```
def works:Boolean = testValue.map[Boolean](_.naire).getOrElse(false)
```

This is a common problem and pops up often since `map` followed by `getOrElse` is very convienent. To properly fix this without the extra types, use a `fold` (catamorphism) over the option:

```
def worksToo:Boolean = testValue.fold(false)(_.naire)
```

By using `fold` you get some added type safety since there's no conversion down to common types. For instance, you can't do this:

```
def failsTypeCheck = testValue.fold("test")(_.naire)
```

While the compiler has no problem with this:

```
def passesTypeCheck = testValue.map(_.naire).getOrElse("test")
```

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA reminds me that `.map(_.predicate).getOrElse(false)` can be simplified to **`.exists(_.predicate)`**, this is even better than using `fold` for booleans!

Comment: @0__ Nice, it was telling me the same thing, I just hadn't noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Boolean` and `scala.Boolean` is not the same. To bridge the gap you have to provide a location where the implicit conversion can do it's work.

There are some patterns to handle these types of Java/Scala interoperability problems:

---

- If it's OK to have a different method to be used from the Scala side, you could use an implicit value class:

```scala
object Container {
  implicit class Test2Scala(val test: Test) extends AnyVal {
    def naireForScala: Boolean = test.naire
  }
}

class Other {
  val testValue = Some(new Test(true))

  import Container._
  def mysteriousCompilationError: Boolean = 
    testValue.map(_.naireForScala).getOrElse(false)
}
```

This does not require additional instances at run-time. It just provides another method to enrich the Java class.

---

- If you can derive a sub class, you could preserve the method's name by using a `DummyImplicit`:

```scala
class Test2(_naire: Boolean) extends Test(_naire) {
  def naire(implicit di: DummyImplicit): Boolean = _naire
}

class Other {
  val testValue = Some(new Test2(true))
  def mysteriousCompilationError: Boolean = 
    testValue.map(_.naire).getOrElse(false)
}
```

The `DummyImplicit` is required to get a different method signature. It's a bit tricky, requires an additional instance at run-time, but `Test2` is a `Test` (in terms of OOP).

---

- Wrap the Java instance in a Scala instance:

```scala
class TestWrapper(test: Test) {
  def naire: Boolean = test.naire
}

class Other {
  val testValue = Some(new TestWrapper(new Test(true)))

  def mysteriousCompilationError: Boolean = 
    testValue.map(_.naire).getOrElse(false)
}
```

Requires an additional instance, you have to add delegates, `TestWrapper` is not a `Test`, but it's simple.